# How to write a function generic over pointer type?

Tags: types, rust

In [rust-clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), we have the [following](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/a24475093954141168d30ef510f20171db4843ac/src/eq_op.rs#L241) function:

```
fn over<X, F>(left: &[X], right: &[X], mut eq_fn: F) -> bool 
        where F: FnMut(&X, &X) -> bool {
    left.len() == right.len() && left.iter().zip(right).all(|(x, y)| 
        eq_fn(x, y))
}
```

As it happens, `rustc`'s AST representation uses a lot of `syntax::ptr::P<T>` pointers. Those dereference to T, and so autoderef implicitly coerces them to `&T` if we use a closure. If we try to use a plain `fn` however, we get a type mismatch:

`` error: type mismatch: the type `fn(&syntax::ast::Expr, &syntax::ast::Expr) -> bool {eq_op::is_exp_equal}` implements the trait `for<'r, 'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r syntax::ast::Expr, &'r syntax::ast::Expr)>`, but the trait `for<'r, 'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r syntax::ptr::P<syntax::ast::Expr>, &'r syntax::ptr::P<syntax::ast::Expr>)>` is required (expected struct `syntax::ptr::P`, found struct `syntax::ast::Expr`) [E0281] ``

Can I change the above function to accept both `&[&T]` and `&[P<T>]` and automatically coerce `P<Expr>` into `&Expr`? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `&T` and `P<T>` implement `Deref<Target = T>`, so you could use that in your bounds:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

fn over<X, F, X1, X2>(left: &[X1], right: &[X2], mut eq_fn: F) -> bool 
        where X1: Deref<Target = X>,
              X2: Deref<Target = X>,
              F: FnMut(&X, &X) -> bool {
    left.len() == right.len() && left.iter().zip(right).all(|(x, y)| 
        eq_fn(x, y))
}
```